# Control the editing of datagridview in winforms

Tags: c++, winforms

I want to control the text that could be entered into my datagridview. More specifically I have datagridview in WinForms application and I want user to enter hexadecimal numbers into it but I want to restrict user to only able to input valid string i. e. number 0-9 and A B C D E and F. I tried to override isinputChar of datagridview class but didn't work. Here is the code. Any help is appreciated thanks.

```
 protected: virtual bool IsInputChar(Keys KeyData) override
       {

           if(KeyData == Keys::D0||KeyData == Keys::D1||KeyData == Keys::D2||KeyData == Keys::D3||KeyData == Keys::D4||KeyData == Keys::D5||KeyData == Keys::D6||KeyData == Keys::D7||KeyData == Keys::D8||KeyData == Keys::D9){
            return true;
           }
           if(KeyData == Keys::NumPad0||KeyData == Keys::NumPad1||KeyData == Keys::NumPad2||KeyData == Keys::NumPad3||KeyData == Keys::NumPad4||KeyData == Keys::NumPad5||KeyData == Keys::NumPad6||KeyData == Keys::NumPad7||KeyData == Keys::NumPad8||KeyData == Keys::NumPad9){
            return true;
           }
           if(KeyData == Keys::A||KeyData == Keys::B||KeyData == Keys::C||KeyData == Keys::D||KeyData == Keys::E||KeyData == Keys::F){
            return true;
           }
           return false;
       }
```

Comment: This code is not `c#`, nor `vb.net`. (*.*sigh*.* _it's c++_ *.*/sigh*.*)

Comment: When you are editing a cell, the control which contains focus and receives key strokes is the editing control of the cell. So if you want to change the behavior of the cell editor, you need to create a new data gridview column, cell and editing control.

Comment: Yeah its CLI(Common Language RunTime Support ) but i can convert a c# solution to cli.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more. I'ma bit new to this @RezaAghaei

Comment: `NumericUpDown` as editing control is an option for you, because it supports hex format. You can use this [MSDN example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730881(v=vs.80).aspx)